# How to move a 2D boat in unity

Tags: unity

I am working on a *2D game* in which boat moves continuously but the direction of the boat is on users touch. Where the user moves its finger the boat moves in that direction. How would I achieve this? Can someone help me in building my logic?

Comment: a 2D boat moving continuously but the movement direction of the boat is on the finger of the user, like if user move its finger from right to left the turn on that direction and moves along its finger. if user picked up its finger the boat keep moving on that direction in which its face.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Do you already have a boat? Is it already moving? Are you somehow registering input? We need to know what you have and what you've tried, unless we cannot help you.

Comment: i have 2D sprite of a boat and i am trying to move that. i want that the boat moves continuously on a specific speed.

Comment: but i actually want that boat rotate on the finger movement of the user, and if user picked up its finger from the screen the boat continuing its movement on that direction in which it is facing.

Comment: Add that information to your question using the "edit" link, and also include the code and scene setup you're using currently. That way, solutions can be matched to your current setup, so you get answers you can put directly into practice.

Comment: Also, you've tagged this question with "unityscript" which is Unity's deprecated JavaScript dialect. Is that really what you want, or would you prefer answers for modern Unity + C#? Similarly, you've used the tag bullet-physics, but Unity does not use the Bullet physics engine. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the point where the touch is in world coordinates (the necessary methods are on the Camera, look for something along the lines of `Camera.screenToWorldPosition` and pick the most suitable one), then get the direction vector by dividing the position of the boat from this and normalizing it:

```
Vector2 direction = (touchWorldPosition - boatPosition).normalized;
```

You can get the angle from this using `Quaternion.LookRotation`:

```
Quaternion touchAngle = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
```

Now rotate the boat towards this angle using `Quaternion.RotateTowards`. The first argument should be the current rotation of the ship, the second is the touchAngle you just calculated and the third argument is the max angle you want the ship to rotate in a frame. The method returns a new quaternion, set the ship's rotation to that.

Now get the forward direction vector of the boat. If the boat looks up by default, then it's `transform.up`, if it looks to the right, then `transform.right`, etc. To move the ship forward just take this direction vector and either apply a force in the same direction to the ship or set the velocity to be this value depending on whether you want a dynamic or kinematic approach respectively.

Comment: You may want to pass Vector 3.forward as the first argument to LookRotation, to get a z-only rotation suitable for 2D